# Allocate memory dynamically for an array of struct in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, dynamically-generated

I have a tricky problem and try to explain it in a short example.

I want to have such struct:

```
struct car_park{
   int count_of_cars;
   struct car{
       int  count_of_seats;
       struct seat{
           int size;
           int color; 
       }seats[];
   }cars[];
}
```

In a carpark there are a count of cars, each car has different count of seats and every seat has different parameter. Max count of cars is 100 and max count of seats is 6, but I don't want to use the arrays of cars and seats static. I would like to allocate the memory dynamically.

And: I want to use it in multiple functions.

```
void read_current_cars(struct car_park *mycars){
// read config file and allocate memory for the struct
...
}

void function_x(struct car_park *mycars){
//... use struct
}

void main(){
struct car_park my;

read_current_cars(&my);
function_x(&my);
}
```

How can I program it? I searched in web, but I can't find a solution. I found only parts, but I can't puzzle it.

Andre

Comment: You just need to allocated the memory using malloc(), use pointers.

Comment: "I would like to allocate the memory dynamically." --> More detail request. 
 Is that like A) 3 cars, 2 seats each or B) 3 cars, car[0] 2 seats, car[1] 4 seats, car[2] 5 seats?

Comment: @chux It is version B)

Comment: Now the next step is to find how you want to pass the information about car count (0 to 100) and  the various seat counts (0 to 6) in to the program.  What is the source of the data? Post some sample _config files_.

Comment: It works with the structs and the allocation too. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is allowed to have a struct with an array with an unspecified length as the last member, such a struct is **not** allowed to be a member of an array.

Since you're dynamically allocating space for these arrays, declare the `cars` and `seats` members as pointers:

```
struct seat {
    int size;
    int color; 
};

struct car {
    int count_of_seats;
    struct seat *seats;
};

struct car_park {
    int count_of_cars;
    struct car *cars;
};
```

Comment: Nice simplification, although `cars` could still be a flexible array member.

Comment: Ah... thanks!

And can you give me a tip regarding the memory allocation? In each car there is the count of seats. But I can't allocate the car array without to know the count of seats... or not? 
I have a knot in the head... :-(

Comment: @Andre When you allocate the `car` array, each instance contains space for a pointer.  Then for each car, you allocate space for an array of `seats` and assign the starting address of that array to the `seats` member.

Comment: Where does C forbid arrays having as element type a struct with a flexible array member?  Certainly such a thing would not serve the OP's purpose, but I'm having trouble finding anything in the standard that actually disallows it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm having trouble finding it myself, but the idea is you can't do pointer arithmetic on a struct with a FAM because its size doesn't include the FAM.

Comment: @dbush, yes, the size of a `struct` with a FAM does not include the FAM, but that doesn't prevent you from doing pointer arithmetic, nor, as far as I can tell, making an array.  It *does* have implications on which elements of each FAM the program is permitted to access, but "none" is sometimes the answer to that question even outside an array.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Suppose you have `struct s { int a; int b; int c[]; };`  Assuming a 4 byte `int` and no padding its size is 8.  You attempt to create a 5 element array of these where each `c` is 5 elements long with `struct s *list = malloc(((sizeof(struct s) + sizeof(int)*5) *5)`.  So element 0 is at offset 0 and element 1 is at offset 28 (8 + 5*4).  But `list + 1` will be at offset `1 * sizeof(struct s)` which is 8.  So you can't successfully index the list, at least not in the normal way.

Comment: Dynamic allocation is a red herring here, @dbush, because the effective type of a dynamically-allocated object is, ultimately, a type that you can declare, and C's behavior is defined in terms of the effective type.  As far as I can tell, the relevant implication of FAMs not contributing to their host struct's sizes is that a strictly conforming program cannot access *any* elements of a FAM of a struct that is an array element.  So as I said, not useful to the OP, but not forbidden as far as I see.  That's not appreciably different from the case of an automatically allocated FAM struct.

Comment: It works with the structs and the allocation too. :-) Thanks!

Comment: @Andre Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.